# Java Swing or SWT method to keep a frame in the background

Tags: java, swing, shell, jframe, swt

I need to keep a frame in the background, only on the surface of the desktop. I have tried JFrame.toBack(), but whenever you click it, it brings it in front of other windows. I need it to keep it in the background, even when it is clicked.

Comment: Have you tried using [`Window#setFocusableWindowState`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setFocusableWindowState(boolean))?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I was going to suggest a focus listener and calling `toBack()` in the appropriate methods

Comment: I have tried both of both of those ideas. The setFocusableWindowState method only seems to keep me from closing the window with alt+f4. The listener idea works, however there is a flash of the window above the other windows before it is sent to the back.